# Mysql stored procedure to update and return a list of matching rows

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I built this stored procedure.  It's supposed to select all the 'non-started' rows from a table we're using as a queue.  Update those rows to mark them as 'STARTING' so they won't be grabbed by another processor and then return those rows back to the requestor for processing.  It works but it seems to be putting an unacceptably high load on our servers.

The main reason for this stored procedure is to select and update the rows so we don't get the same row selected by multiple processors at the same time.

I'm not a DBA and I had to learn some stored procedure and cursor stuff on the fly so maybe I'm missing something obvious to someone else.  I'm guessing there is a way to do this without completely overloading our db servers.  Any help is appreciated.

We use a MySql db 5.6.xx with a Java/Tomcat web-app.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`admin`@`%` PROCEDURE `select_and_start_non_started`(
    IN p_companyId INT(11),
    IN p_howMany INT, 
    IN p_instance varchar(50),
    IN p_status varchar(50), 
    IN p_updateBy varchar(50)
)
BEGIN


    DECLARE  v_currentId        INT;
    DECLARE  v_loopDone         INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE  v_loopCounter      INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE  v_idList           VARCHAR(1024) DEFAULT NULL;

    DECLARE queue_csr CURSOR FOR 
        SELECT id FROM queue 
            WHERE (status in (_utf8'NEW' COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci, 
                              _utf8'RESTARTED' COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci, 
                              _utf8'WAITING' COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci, 
                              _utf8'QUEUED' COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci)) 
              AND if(LENGTH(p_companyId) > 0, companyid=p_companyId, true)                       
         LIMIT p_howMany FOR UPDATE;

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET v_loopDone=1;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION 
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK;
        SET autocommit = TRUE;
        RESIGNAL;
    END;

    SET v_idList = "";

    SET autocommit = FALSE;
    START TRANSACTION;

    OPEN queue_csr;
    iq_loop:LOOP
        FETCH queue_csr INTO v_currentId;
        IF v_loopDone THEN LEAVE iq_loop; END IF;


        UPDATE queue SET status = p_status COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci, updatedDate=NOW(), updatedBy=p_updateBy, recordStatus=p_instance WHERE id = v_currentId;
        SET v_idList = CONCAT(v_idList, ",", v_currentId);
        SET v_loopCounter=v_loopCounter+1;
        IF v_loopCounter > p_howMany THEN LEAVE iq_loop; END IF;

    END LOOP iq_loop;
    CLOSE queue_csr;
    SET v_loopDone=0;

    COMMIT;
    SET autocommit = TRUE;

    SELECT * FROM queue q WHERE FIND_IN_SET(id, v_idList);

END
```

Answer (score 2):

*It works but it seems to be putting an unacceptably high load on our servers.*

As 2 first steps,

1. It might be helpful to have "indexes" on the columns: status and
   companyid. If you don't have the indexes, you can create them using:

   ```
   alter table select_and_start_non_started add index (status);
   alter table select_and_start_non_started add index(companyid);
   ```
2. p_companyId is an integer, so I am not sure why you are taking its length. Anyway, since LENGTH(p_companyId) is a constant, instead of calling it for every row, you may want to save it in a variable:

```
declare v_companyid_len int;
set v_companyid_len=LENGTH(p_companyId);
BEGIN
DECLARE queue_csr CURSOR FOR .... AND if(v_companyid_len>0 ...
```

Comment: Thank you for the info, I appreciate it!  I did just put an index on the companyId and that helped a lot.  I'll also look at doing it for status.  The variable for v_company_id is because sometimes it's not passed in so LENGTH(companyId) was simply to make sure we had a value to compare to.  I like your idea though.  I'll give it a shot.  Thanks again.